# Look for built-in class like StructuralEqualityComparer<T> with generic version

Tags: c#, linq

Assume I have two classes `A` and `B` with different number of properties:

```
class A
{
    public int Pro1  { get; set; }
    public string Pro2 { get; set; }   
}

class B
{
    public int Pro1 { get; set; }
    public string Pro2 { get; set; }
    public bool Pro3 { get; set; }
}
```

In order to do *structural equality comparison* to use in Lamda methods like: Distinct, Intesect... I have to build two custom `EqualityComparer`:

```
public class CustomComparerA : EqualityComparer<A> {} 
// use all Pro1 and Pro2

public class CustomComparerB : EqualityComparer<B> {} 
// use all Pro1, Pro2 and Pro3
```

Let's if I have 10 entities, I have to build 10 custom comparers, seems it is no much clean in code. Took a look around and found out .NET framework has a built-in class `StructuralEqualityComparer` but it marked as `internal`, and it does not have *generic version*. What I look is:

```
StructuralEqualityComparer<T>
```

So that I can re-use:

```
listA.Distinct(new Structuralequalitycomparer<A>())
listA.Distinct(new Structuralequalitycomparer<B>())
```

Does anyone know built-in class .NET to support this? If not, is there any reason?

Or we have to manage by ourselves?

Comment: Looking at `StructuralEqualityComparer`, it doesn't actually _do_ anything interesting. It just asks the first object whether it equals the second, using a particular interface if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to build by `StructuralEqualityComparer<T>` myself since .NET does not supports this with the reasons mentioned on dasblinkenlight's answer, thanks dasblinkenlight.

```
private class StructuralEqualityComparer<T> : EqualityComparer<T> where T : class
{
    public override bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return typeof(T).GetProperties()
                         .All(pro => pro.GetValue(x).Equals(pro.GetValue(y)));

    }

    public override int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        int hashCode = typeof(T).GetProperties()
                                .Aggregate(0, (current, pro) => 
                                     current ^ pro.GetValue(obj).GetHashCode());

        return hashCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will be rather slow, because it would use reflection APIs in very time-sensitive operations. You can relatively easily convert them to LINQ expressions and compile them, following the suggestion from my answer and the code of your answer as a template for building these expressions.